# Format Phone Numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

**My goal**

I would like to format phone numbers that are currently stored in my database as 1112223333, to appear as this format 111-222-3333. I'm only collecting phone numbers from the United States.

**Details about my goal**

When I collect users phone numbers I'm only collecting 10 numeric values and saving them as a string in my database as `varchar(10)`. Only numeric values are permitted to be entered.

I'm not receiving any error messages and I'm not sure what is needed to format the phone numbers to the desired format that I need. I'm using ASP.NET Core MVC, C# and SQL Server.

**ApplicationFormViewModel**

This is how I'm collecting the phone number format in my view model.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is required")]
[Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
[RegularExpression(@"^1?[0-9]{10}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid Phone number")]
public string AppPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Currently using the following code below to display the phone number:

```
<span class="details-span-value">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Applications.AppPhoneNumber)</span>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the DisplayFormat attribute?

Comment: Write a method that uses Substring or a RegEx to break your string into its constituent pieces, and string.Join to put them together with hyphens in between.

Comment: What about someone who has an extension as part of their phone number?

Comment: It's not totally clear whether you are asking about saving the numbers formatted or keeping them as they are and formatting them for display. I suspect most people would advise the latter.

Comment: Your regex allows 11 numbers as well as 10

Comment: .. if the number starts with 1

Comment: @gunr2171 No, I have not tried adding a DisplayFormat attribute. I'm not sure what I would need to add to the DisplayFormat attribute on the Details Page.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior would you be willing to help me with this? I'm not that knowledgeable yet.

Comment: @padeso I don't want to save the numbers formatted. I only want to display the phone numbers as 111-222-3333. I want the phone numbers to stay in the database as 1112223333.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior That's a bad idea if you just want to display them formatted - you don't need to `Join` just for output, and you are creating garbage and using memory for no reason.

Comment: @gunr2171 How would that help with a `string` value?

Comment: Since you have the property marked `DataType.PhoneNumber`, you can create a custom display template named PhoneNumber.cshtml in the DisplayTemplates folder to format the output. Perhaps something like `@model string @Model.Substring(0,3)+"-"+Model.Substring(3,3)+"-"+Model.Substring(6)

Comment: @user18776105: This is a question/answer site. If you [ask a question that has a clear answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), we're happy to help. But we are not here to write code for you. You need to spend time learning on your own and trying different things. Then, when you get stuck on one very specific point, create a question showing the code you've written and explaining what you know about how it isn't working correctly.

Comment: @NetMage: I don't think the post makes the requirements clear enough to know what's a "Bad Idea". I think creating a custom display template as you recommend is a great approach. It also creates far more overhead than a string.Join, and it will impact how phone numbers are displayed across the entire application, and it's difficult to unit test to make sure it handles various types of inputs (like 11-digit numbers). There are pros and cons to various approaches.

Comment: @NetMage I created a DisplayTemplate called AppPhoneNumber.cshtml and placed in within the View for the Controller I need to call. I never used DisplayTemplates before, but I tried to add what you mentioned. I did not receive any errors or warnings in my code but the phone number format is still 111222333.

Comment: @user18776105: The display template file needs to have a specific name and be placed in a specific location. Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/display-templates?view=aspnetcore-7.0#display-templates

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I have followed the rules to adding a question to the best of my knowledge. As I clearly stated, I'm learning. I'm not as knowledgeable as you, but I believe the question I posted makes perfect sense with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: `Html.DisplayFor` can take a second parameter that is the DisplayTemplate name - pass in "AppPhoneNumber" if you don't want to transform all phone numbers in your application. If you do, change the filename to be `PhoneNumber` so it matches the `DataType` you have used.

Comment: @NetMage thank you for your last comment, that helped me get in the right direction to resolve this issue. I had to use an “if” statement though for phone numbers that were not required therefore would not be displayed.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior thank you for providing the link, that also helped me to better understand what DisplayTemplates are about.